# Facebook share - phonegap

Tags: facebook, cordova

I use this link to share url on facebook: http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com 
and it works fine on mobile devices.

How can I share text? I tried with &text= and &t= but when I click "Share" it opens a page that says: "Post a link to your profile" and share doesn't work.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this tutorial / example for how to use the Graph API in phonegap, the current Facebook plugin is weak to say the least. This method will allow you to post, share, upload and really what ever you want.

The GIT Project here
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/phonegapFacebookApp

Here is the blog post it is pretty detailed and should help
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88

Answer (score 0):

The sharer.php link is being deprecated.  You should use the like plugin instead.  It has the share functionality.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/